# Show that $ U(n) $ is non-albelian for $n \geq 2$.

Tags: group-theory

U(n) is a group consisting of unitary n by n matrices under matrix multiplication.

[image]

I have proved the first bit of the question. Also, I have proved that U(n) is a group by showing that indentity exists, inverse exists, showing matrix multiplication is associative and that it's closed under matrix multiplication.

Also, U(1) is albelian as it's a 1 by 1 matrix and hence commutative.

However, I am stuck on the last part, showing $U(n)$ is non-albelian for $n \geq 2 $.

I guess I have to find example of matrices which shows that some elements don't commute. But I haven't been able to find one.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried writing down a couple of non-diagonal elements of $U(2)$ in a basis and calculating their commutator? If you find those you're done, because you can embed $U(2)$ in $U(n)$ for $n > 2$ (how can you embed $2 \times 2$ matrices in a $n \times n$ matrix?).

Answer (score 1):

You may think of $U(n)$ as the complex analogue of $O(n),$ the group of linear isometries of real $n$-space. This lets us think more geometrically. You know that $O(2)$ is not abelian: simply take, say, matrices corresponding to a rotation by $\pi/2$ and a reflection across the $x$ axis. You may also view these matrices as elements of $U(2),$ acting on $\mathbb{C}^2$ this time. Now simply view these as elements of $U(n)$ which fix the other $n-2$ coordinates.